# Set Request Header and Forward to another application

Tags: java, servlets, request-headers

I am writing a Java based Web application, which, in the actual production environment would be front-ended by another application which would set certain HTTP request headers before the request hits my application.

However, in the development environment I do not have the front-ending application, for which I need to create a mock web application that simulates the same behavior. i.e. this mock application should set the request headers and redirect or forward or whatever that I do not know :) to a certain page in my application.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following articles may help you:

- [Adding Header Information to an existing HTTP Request](http://bijubnair.blogspot.com/2008/12/adding-header-information-to-existing.html)
- [How to modify request headers in a J2EE web
  application.](http://vangjee.wordpress.com/2009/02/25/how-to-modify-request-headers-in-a-j2ee-web-application/)

---

P.S.
I am sorry I provided only links, that was one of my early answer on SO ))

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to modify your code as suggested by @user1979427 you can use a proxy server to modify headers or add headers on the fly.

For example in Apache HTTPD you would add something like below and proxy the

```
Header add HEADER "HEADERVALUE"
RequestHeader set HEADER "HEADERVALUE"
```

Refer to [HTTPD doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a AddReqHeaderForFrowardWrapper request wrapper passing the headername and header values. And, override the request header related methods to return your custom header.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tracer to implement this. 
There are frameworks available to support this implementation.
Spring has Sleuth, Zipkin, OpenTracing available. 
I find OpenTracing to be easy to use without worrying about dependency conflicts.
Read more about it here: https://opentracing.io/guides/java/

Answer (score -3):

Instead of writing a mock application, I used a browser add-on that allowed me to add custom headers!

Answer (score -7):

For setting header in java, you can use:

```
request.setHeader(attributeName, attributeValue);
```

And for redirecting to another page, you can use:

```
request.sendRedirect(URL);
```

Comment: AFAIK - There is no `request.setHeader`. Neither does `request.sendRedirect` exists. I guess it is a typo for `response`. However, even when I tried that, the request headers are not received in my application.